# How to install specific kernel-ml-devel by yum

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to install kernel-ml-devel for debugging the kernel, the version of kernel as follow:

```bash
root@localhost:/usr/src/kernels# uname -r
5.4.142-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
root@localhost:/usr/src/kernels# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
```

However, when I install the kernel-ml-kernel by yum, the wrong version is resolved:

```bash
root@localhost:/usr/src/debug# yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml-{devel,perf}
No package kernel-ml-perf available.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel-ml-devel.x86_64 0:5.18.1-1.el7.elrepo will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                                Version                                            Repository                                  Size
======================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel-ml-devel                              x86_64                              5.18.1-1.el7.elrepo                                elrepo-kernel                               14 M

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package
```

So, my question is how to install the kernel-ml-devel as same as the version I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Redhat/Fedora based distros normally only a single kernel package and its development subpackage are available. If you have some old version of the Linux kernel package installed you basically need to Google to find if there are mirrors which still have its development version.

Comment: Finally i found the corresponding kernel devel package from `https://linux.cc.iitk.ac.in/mirror/centos/elrepo/kernel/el7/x86_64/RPMS/`,thanks for you tip